# Is there a way to use AUCTeX'S HEAD from package.el?

Tags: auctex, package

There's recently been a commit to AUCTeX that I would like to start using right away, but I would like to use the built-in package system to manage the updates.  Is there a way to use `package.el` to pull in AUCTeX's `HEAD` rather than tags?

(This might be a misunderstanding of how the package system actually works. If so, forgive me `:)`.)

Comment: Do you mean the last commit in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git?  The AUCTeX package provided in GNU Elpa in built from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs/elpa.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/externals/auctex which is a separate repository, but something like `package-install-file` can be used to install "original" AUCTeX.

Comment: You don't say what version of emacs you're using. If its the git development version of emacs-25 then beware of the `font-latex-jit-lock-force-redisplay' bug you can get using auctex. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-02/msg01800.html. I have seen the bug with auctex-11.88.

Comment: @m43cap: This has been fixed in AUCTeX long time ago, the fix is included in version 11.88

Comment: @SeanAllred  It [has been reported](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/5691) that with [`el-get`](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) is possible to install the latest revision of upstream AUCTeX git repository.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to usepackage.el to pull in AUCTeX's HEAD rather than tags?

`package.el` doesn't pull in tags, it pulls in whichever single version the server makes available. So no, **package.el has no control over what is offered to it by the server**. It just so happens that some servers offer the latest tag.

---

What you can do is clone the repo yourself, keep it updated, and use package.el to install this clone you have. If you're using emacs 25 already, you can visit the directory and use `package-install-from-buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) to manage dependencies in order to achieve that, but you're likely already aware of such an alternative that introduces another program.